# Cannot start memcached

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, memcached, dalli

I cannot get `memcached` to run on my server.
This is what I tried so far:

```
% sudo systemctl start memcached # no output
% sudo systemctl status memcached.service
● memcached.service - memcached daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/memcached.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-02-16 17:45:09 CET; 4s ago
  Process: 22725 ExecStart=/usr/share/memcached/scripts/systemd-memcached-wrapper /etc/memcached.conf (code=exited, status=71)
 Main PID: 22725 (code=exited, status=71)

systemd[1]: Started memcached daemon.
systemd-memcached-wrapper[22725]: bind(): Cannot assign requested address
systemd-memcached-wrapper[22725]: failed to listen on TCP port 11211: Cannot assign requested address
systemd[1]: memcached.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=71/n/a
systemd[1]: memcached.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd[1]: memcached.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I am running Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS

How can I start my memcached service?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look into /etc/memcached.conf there might be written sth. like 
-l xxx.xx.xx.xx
If you are trying to connect via localhost: just comment the line.
If you are trying to connect from somewhere else check the IP for correctness.